# Show that $(0,1)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ and that $[0,1]$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

**My Question:** I want to show that the interval $(0,1)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$  and that $[0,1]$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$. I proved the latter, but I felt that it was clumsy and could be refined. If you could also show that $(0,1)$ is open that would be great; these are the simplest problems that I can think of, and I am concerned with the format of the proof (my intuition tells me that they are both true). I am working with the following definitions (I may have made an error while translating the definitions into symbolic logic, if so please correct me). Thanks!

**Definitions:**
A set $G$
  in $\mathbb{R}^{p}$
  is said to be **open in** $\mathbb{R}^{p}$
  if for all $x$
  in $G$
  ,there exists an $r>0$
  , such that for each $y$
  in $\mathbb{R}^{p}$
  satisfying the condition $\|x-y\|<r$
  also belong to $G$.
  Or, even more formally we could write $$G\text{ is an }\textbf{open set} \iff G\subset\mathbb{R}^{p}\wedge\forall x\in G\exists r>0\in\mathbb{R}\left(\forall y\in\mathbb{R}^{p}\left(\|x-y\|<r\iff y\in G\right)\right).$$

Using the definition of an open ball $\mathcal{B}(x,r)=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^{p}\::\:\|x-y\|<r\}$
 , where $x$
  is the center of the ball and $r>0$
  is the radius of the ball, then we can rephrase the definition of an **open set** by saying that $G$
  is open if every point $x$
  in $G$
  is the center of some open ball contained entirely in $G.$  Again more formally we can write

$$G \text{ is an }\textbf{open set}\iff G\subset\mathbb{R}^{p}\wedge\forall x\in G\exists r>0\in\mathbb{R}\left(\mathcal{B}(x,r)\subset G\right).$$

**My work:**

Consider the set $F=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\::\:0\leqslant x\leqslant1\}\subset\mathbb{R}$
 , is $F$
  an open set?

No! *proof.* Since, we know that $G$
  is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{p}$
 , we need only consider the second conjunct in the bi-conditional above. The negation of the statement $\forall x\in G\exists r>0\in\mathbb{R}\left(\mathcal{B}(x,r)\subset G\right)$
  is, $\exists x\in G\forall r>0\in\mathbb{R}\left(\mathcal{B}(x,r)\not\subset G\right)$
 .

Now let us consider the point $x=1$ in $F$
 then we must consider all of the balls centered at $1$ with a radius $r>0$, i.e. ${\cal B}(1,r)=\{y\in\mathbb{R}\::\:|1-y|<r\}$. If we want to show that the negation is false then we need to find a ball such that for each $y\in{\cal B}(1,r)$, $y\in G$. However, by the Archimedes property we have that we know that for all $r>0$
  that there will always be a number $y^*=1/n$ such that  $0<y^*<r$
 , and that $(1+y^*)\in{\cal B}(1,r)$
  while $(1+y^*)\notin G$
 . Therefore given the element $1$
  in $F$
 , ${\cal B}(1,r)\not\subset G$
  for all $r>0$
 ; hence, $F$
  is not an open set.

Comment: Too many logical symbols! For the fact that $[0,1]$ is not open observe that any interval $(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)$ contains a number not in our set. For $(0,1)$, if $x$ is in the set, let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}\min(x,1-x)$. Then the interval $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$ is a subset of $(0,1)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas are all of the logical symbols at least correct? I usually try to write most questions into logic first it helps me think about where to start, its a personal preference I think. The only problem is when I write the logic wrong!

Comment: Consider for example (I copied, omitting only displaymath) $G\text{ is an }\textbf{open set} \iff G\subset\mathbb{R}^{p}\wedge\forall x\in G\exists r>0\in\mathbb{R}\left(\forall y\in\mathbb{R}^{p}\left(\|x-y\|<r\iff y\in G\right)\right)$. Not true, the last $\iff$ is wrong, it should be $\implies$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks, for pointing that out. I was confused about that when I was writing the logic out. I thought that the English insinuated if and only if. How were you able to distinguish the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you've got exactly the right idea: Any ball centered at $1$ must contain a number greater than $1$. For a more direct proof that's constructive (as opposed to just invoking the Archimdean property), consider:

> Suppose that $[0, 1]$ is open. Then there exists an $r > 0$ such that whenever $|y - 1| < r$, we have $y \in [0, 1]$. Choose $$y = 1 + \frac{r}{2}$$
>   This leads to a contradiction since $|y - 1| = |r/2| < r$ but $y \notin [0, 1]$.

---

As a hint to show that $(0, 1)$ is open, let $x \in (0, 1)$ be given. Consider $$r = \frac{\min(x, 1 - x)}{2}$$
and show that that $\mathcal{B}(x, r) \subseteq (0, 1)$.

Comment: I like this proof thanks! If it is not to0 much to ask could you add the proof that $(0,1)$ is open for a future reference?

Comment: @JimmyJackson I've added a hint towards that proof.

Comment: Thanks! I need to get some sleep, I will work it out in the morning. Thanks for your help.